# How to parcel two object which are in a bidirectional one-to-one relationship?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I have two object like these that I want to send through `Intent` implementing `Parcelable` interface:

```
class Foo implements Parcelable
{
    private Bar bar;

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeParcelable(bar, flags);
    }
}

class Bar implements Parcelable
{
    private Foo foo;

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeParcelable(foo, flags);
    }
}
```

How can I implement correctly the `Parcelable` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

In `writeToParcel` of `Foo` class write all fields of `Foo` instance without `Bar` field and all fields  of `Bar` instance without `Foo` field.

Then in `Foo(Parcel in)` read all fields of `Foo` and use fields of `Bar` to create the `Bar` instance and link both objects together.

Comment: ok, thank you, I've understand. and if I've got another object which contains a `DateTime` field, should I use `writeValue` or `writeTypedObject` to write this field?

Comment: You can use `writeValue` if `DateTime` is `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and `writeTypedObject` only if `DateTime` is `Parcelable`.